# how to compare and swap two arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, swap

I have tried the following codes, but I'm still getting errors. It seems I have a problem in comparing two arrays, and checking if they point at one array. I also have a problem in swapping two arrays so that they can interchange their values. Additionally, removing values that are the same in an array seems to be so hard. The codes below is how I pictured them, but I'm still getting errors even after trying different approaches to the problems. Please help me understand how to compare two arrays, specifically on these codes.

```
public class ArraySwap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Some test code
        ArraySwap swapper = new ArraySwap();
        int[] a = {1, 2, 3}; //initialize array a[]
        int[] b = a;  //initialize array b[]
        System.out.println(swapper.arrayEquals(a, b));

        int[] arr = {1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 6, 8, 7, 9, 9, 8, 9, 1};
        ArraySwap c = new ArraySwap();
        arr = c.removeDuplicates(arr);
        for (Integer i : arr) {
            System.out.print(i);
        }
        System.out.println();

    }

    /*
      Return true if the values in a are the same as the values in b
     */
    public boolean arrayValuesEqual(int[] a, int[] b) {
        if (Arrays.equals(a, b)) {
            return true;   //returning true
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /*
      Return true if a and b point to the same array
     */
    public boolean arrayEquals(int[] a, int[] b) {
        if (a.length == b.length) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Swap a and b WITHOUT doing an elementwise copy.
     */
    public void swap(int[] a, int[] b) {

        int temp = a[0];
        a[0] = b[0];
        b[0] = temp;
    }
}
/*
     * Returns true if a and b have the same name
     */

    public boolean sameName(Person a, Person b) {
        if (a == b) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Given an array of positive integers, removes duplicates
     * in the array.
     * @return a contiguous array with the remaining integers 
     * with a length equal to the number of remaining integers
     */
    public int[] removeDuplicates(int[] integers) {
        int[] toReturn = new int[];
        for (int i = 0; i > integers.length; i++) {
            if (i + 1 > integers.length) {
                if (integers[i] == integers[i + 1]) {
                    remove.integers[i];
                }

            }
            toReturn = integers[i];
        }
        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

Comment: `but I'm still getting errors` ... perhaps tell us what the errors are and we won't need to use our mystical SO Telepathy skills...

Comment: Why have you dumped so many random and unconnected methods in your question? Also, `sameName` is just wrong. Don't compare reference equality.

Answer (score 2):

You seemed to have asked a few questions in one and it's not really clear what your goal is....

In your ***arrayValuesEqual()*** you're comparing arrays a & b with *.equals* this method is comparing a shallow copy of the arrays. If you want to do a deep copy you should use *.deepEquals()*.  see more info here: [comparing arrays in java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/compare-two-arrays-java/)

in your ***arrayEquals*** method the description reads if they point to the same array, but all you're doing is checking the length.. this does not prove that the contains are the same...

your ***swap*** method - will this work if it's a multidimensional array? What if they are not the same length array? You seem to be writing code for a specific case and not considering various test cases.

Your ***sameName*** method - that's not how you compare objects. the == compares object references, it checks to see if the two operands point to the same object (not *equivalent* objects, the **same** object). You will need to override an equals method for the Person object.